# How to insert into an existing mysql database table using flask and sqlalchemy

Tags: python, rest, flask, sqlalchemy, flask-sqlalchemy

Ok I am trying to insert a new row into an existing mysql database table using a restful API application based on Flask and sqlalchemy. I want it to take the values from the incoming http POST request and then create a new row in the "object" table of the given database with the values received from the POST request.

Note: The app is running via a wsgi setup with httpd apache server (cent os 6.6)

The restful API portion works as intended but I can't seem to get my head around the sqlalchemy part. I need some clear specific advice for a novice.

The sample code below causes an error on line 30 that reads (the 8 is actually the 8 params in my actual code, only 2 in this sample code):

"TypeError: **init**() takes exactly 1 argument (8 given)"

Not sure what I am doing wrong... sorry code is long, you will have to scroll.

```
#! usr/bin/python
from flask import Flask, jsonify, request
from flask_restful import reqparse, abort, Resource, Api
from flask_sqlalchemy import SQLAlchemy
from sqlalchemy import create_engine, MetaData, Table, Column, Integer, Text, DateTime, ForeignKey
from sqlalchemy.ext.declarative import declarative_base
from sqlalchemy.orm import relationship, backref, scoped_session, sessionmaker

app = Flask(__name__)
api = Api(app)

engine = create_engine('mysql+pymysql://user_name:password@1.1.1.1:3306/database', echo=True)
Base = declarative_base()
metadata = MetaData()
Base.metadata.reflect(engine)

class Object(Base):
    __table__ = Table('object', metadata, autoload = True, autoload_with=engine)

class submitObject(Resource):
    def post(self):

        request_data = request.get_json(force=True)

        r_object_id = request_data['object_id']
        r_object_name = request_data['object_name']

        r_object_json = jsonify(object_id=r_object_id, object_name=r_object_name)

        r_object_row = Object(r_object_id, r_object_name)

        db_session = scoped_session(sessionmaker(bind=engine))

        db_session.add(r_object_row)
        db_session.commit()
        db_session.remove()

        return r_ticket_json

api.add_resource(submitObject, '/object/submit')

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.debug = True
    app.run()
```

Any assistance is greatly appreciated!!

Comment: Which line is line 48? There are not 48 lines in this snippet.

Comment: I feel the way you creating an Object has something to do with it. Look at line `r_object_row = Object( .. , ..)`. I don't see you have defined schema for the table anywhere. Without schema, I see the ORM yelling, when you are trying to put data into it.

Comment: Please include the full traceback when asking for debugging help.

Comment: Sorry line 48 was for my real code, I reformatted this for stack overflow, that would put the error on line 30 in this example sorry. This line

r_object_row = Object(r_object_id, r_object_name)

Comment: @Vasif That is exactly what it is I am just not sure how to define the schema since it is an existing database and table. I was hoping that using autoload would automatically define the schema, but obviously that is not the case. I don't so much need debug help as I need syntax/architecture help... I am missing a critical component here but I am a noob and can't see what it is.

Comment: Please don't down vote this, I am trying my best to understand this and I need help.

Comment: @JOG88, I don't really work with SQLalchemy a lot. Guess your declaration of mapping isn't correct. see this link for a few examples on how to declare a Class. http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/orm/mapping_styles.html#declarative-mapping.

Answer (score 1):

The fix was to change the way the class was instantiated.

I changed line 30 from this:

```
r_object_row = Object(r_object_id, r_object_name)
```

to this:

```
r_object_row = Object()

r_object_row.id = r_object_id
r_object_row.name = r_object_name
```